# How to include custom statements/directive in C# code generated by NSwag?

Tags: c#, swagger, using-directives, nswag

I generated C# code from a Swagger definition and was wondering if there is a configuration parameter to automatically include `using` statements in the generated files. I found this link https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/wiki/NSwag-Configuration-Document with config-parameters but none of these seems to make the trick. To be more clear, my file at the moment looks like this at the top:

[image]

I would like the autogenerated file to include `using` statements like this:

[image]

Any help or tips are very appretiated.

Comment: What codegen do you use - Swagger Codegen (as mentioned in the tags) or NSwag (as mentioned in the question)?

Comment: @Helen NSwag as mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your NSwag configuration, you can set:

```
"openApiToCSharpClient": {
  ...
  "additionalNamespaceUsages": [
    "RDT.Api.DomainModels"
  ],
  ...
  "namespace": "RDT.Api.Repository",
  ...
}
```

Alternately, NSwagStudio includes an option 'Additional Namespace Usages'.

[image: NSwagStudio Config]

To keep the settings, you can save your `.nswag` file for future use